# Display average of case resolution times in HH:MM:SS

Tags: apex, visualforce

In my controller I obtain the average using an aggregate query:

```
        AggregateResult[] avgWait = [Select Avg(Time_Case_In_Queue__c) from case where CreatedDate = TODAY;
            str2 = '' + avgWait[0].get('expr0');
            avgWaitTime = Double.ValueOf(str2);

        AggregateResult[] avgHandle = [Select Avg(Task_Age__c) from case where CreatedDate = TODAY AND Task_End_Time__c != null];
            avgHandleTime = 0.0;
            str3 = '' + avgHandle[0].get('expr0');
            avgHandleTIme = Double.ValueOf(str3);
```

And in my page, I display the double value using:

```
<apex:outputLabel >Avg Wait Time: </apex:outputLabel>
<apex:outputText >{!avgWaitTime}</apex:outputText>
<apex:outputLabel >Avg Handle Time: </apex:outputLabel>
<apex:outputText >{!avgHandleTime}</apex:outputText>
```

The formula fields (Time_Case_In_Queue__c & Task_Age__c) return the average in minutes, but business users are used to hh:mm:ss display. I'm not against using javascript, but is there an easy way to format it using the MessageFormat class. I've tried w/ little success. Please advise

Comment: I would recommend formatting it into a string in Apex to use for display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
List<Double> avgTimes = new List<Double>{0, 0.25, 0.5, 1.1, 15.5, 59.90, 75.6667};

for(Double d : avgTimes){
    Time t = time.newInstance(0,0,0,0).addSeconds(Integer.valueOf(d * 60));
    System.debug(t);
}

00:00:00.000Z
00:00:15.000Z
00:00:30.000Z
00:01:06.000Z
00:15:30.000Z
00:59:54.000Z
01:15:40.000Z
```

Whether you'll pass these time values to `<apex:outputText>` or just extract `t.getHours()`,`t.getMinutes()` etc and pass it to String.format - your call :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a Collection of APEX Utils classes available for free under the Apache Commons License code at http://code.google.com/p/apex-lang/. The class I think you'll want to look at is called the DateForumla class. You'd need to convert your double into an integer in order to use it.

BTW, I believe this code is also available as a freebie app on the App Exchange, but if you use Eclipse, this is where you'll likely want to get it from.